# Create a new column comparing two rows

Tags: python, pandas

I am working on a COVID-19 dataset with total cases and total deaths at the last day of each month for each city since march. But I would like to create a column which tells me the number of new cases for every city in each of these months.

My logic is: if the value in the cell from the `'city_ibge_code'` column in position p is the same as the value in position p-1, it should create a new column that is the difference between the number of cases in two months. And if the values are different (that shows that are different cities), just pass that value to the new column.

`casos_full`: is the dataframe with the cities and the number of cases and deaths in march, april, may, june, july, august and semptember.
`city_ibge_code`: is the code for each city in the dataframe - each city has a unique code.

And there also is a "`date`" column - which represents the last day of the month

```
for rows in casos_full:
    if rows['city_ibge_code'] ==  rows['city_ibge_code'].shift(1):
        rows['New Cases'] = rows['last_available_confirmed'] - rows['last_available_confirmed'].shift(1)
    else:
        rows['New Cases'] = rows['last_available_confirmed']
```

Comment: Why not just groupby and calculate the difference `casos_full.groupby('city_ibge_code')['last_available_confirmed'].diff()` and then fillna?

Comment: @It_is_Chris I had a similar idea to this one before trying the for loop. Anyways, that worked well, thanks! Just gonna need to find a way to use the fillna() with the correct number os cases for each city.

Comment: `casos_full.groupby('city_ibge_code')['last_available_confirmed'].diff().fillna(casos_full['last_available_confirmed'])`

Answer (score 0):

`rows` here is a view of the line. You need to update the actual dataframe. If I understood your problem correctly.

```
for i, rows in enumerate(casos_full):
    if rows['city_ibge_code'] ==  rows['city_ibge_code'].shift(1):
        casos_full[i]['New Cases'] = rows['last_available_confirmed'] - rows['last_available_confirmed'].shift(1)
    else:
        casos_full[i]['New Cases'] = rows['last_available_confirmed']
```

Please give more precision on your problem so we can help.